# Why would an application use CSC.EXE?

Tags: .net, dll, runtime, csc

I understand that CSC.EXE is a C# compiler used by Visual Studio.

But why would an already built DotNet application be using CSC.EXE?

When I run ProcMon I see the application loading it's DLLs, but I also see CSC.EXE reading the DLLs.

Is CSC.EXE part of the standard DotNet Client framework runtime?

Comment: what is the application in this context? is it a web app that might be compiling pages at runtime? does it make use of serialization? for example, `XmlSerializer` works by generating C# at runtime (after analyzing your type model) that it feeds through the compiler to get a runtime-generated serializer implementation; there are *lots* of meta-programming implementations that make use of the compiler; not all do, note - you can also emit IL directly at runtime (same outcome, but you never touch the C# compiler)

Comment: Just a regular DotNet app - not a web app.  So there are times when the application has to invoke CSC.EXE for some things? Can you give me an example?

Comment: I already gave two :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant a code example.

Comment: fine... `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(someType);`